# R shiny : renderDataTable of a global environment object

Tags: r, shiny

I have an object named "map_choice" which value can be : "1_1","1_2","1_3"...
And I have created some data frames objects in my global environment named : "T_1_1","T_1_2","T_1_3"...
I'm trying to render the matching data frame with these lines in my Server.R but I have this error message : "'data' must be 2-dimensional (e.g. data frame or matrix)"

Server.R :

```
output$tab_map = renderDataTable({paste(T_,map_choice)}) # paste to 
                                              match data frame name

output$box1 <- renderUI({
box(title = input$maps, dataTableOutput("tab_map")) # dynamic title of 
                                                               the box
})
```

And this line in Ui.R :

```
uiOutput("box1")
```

I suppose it's an easy thing to do but I didn't manage to do it.

Thank you for helping a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is `get`. Also make sure you use `paste0`

```
output$tab_map = renderDataTable({
  get(paste0("T_",map_choice))
})
```

Comment: Great ! Thank you one more time Warmoverflow. I didn't know there is a "paste0" instruction. I should have looked documentation, sorry, but I would have never known for the "get" one. Thanks a lot.